# unable to kill process / logout on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-access, process

My own console .net application stuck in a "ghost" stage. It just shows a window that i can't close. It doesn't show up as a process in the task manager.

when i try to "find windows process" using Process Explorer (from sysinternals) it says there is no process that owns that window or something like that.

The problem is that it doesn't allow me to logout or reboot the server (remotely) because logoff process keeps waiting on that window to close.

shutdown /r /f also is stuck waiting for it.

I can probably have somebody go an reboot the server but i'd like to know if there is a way to close that process, close that session or force logout remotely.

This is windows server 2003, but i had the same issue on XP just a few days ago.

Comment: Can you post a little about the what the console app does?  Maybe we can help you to track down why it's not shutting down properly.

Comment: it's a self hosted WCF service. It is multithreaded listening to external (internet) webservice and sending messages to others.

Another unknown is i am not sure if it was started from VisualStudio with debugger attached or not. Also i don't remember how i stopped it (pause button or ctrl+c).

But the thing is it's not running, there is no process in the process explorer. the ports it's attaching to are available.

Answer (score 1):

The usual cuprit is that the WCF selfhost service is having problem with multi-session invocation. For you to verify if this is the case, login as administrator on the win2003 machine and run the task manager, then show all the process owned by *all users. See if some WCF selfhost process is still in memory run by other users.

If indeed WCF selfhost multi-session problem is really the problem, tell the WCF selfhost developer to host his WCF service into windows service so that single instance of WCF service will be kept running.